# String color format in VScode

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

well, what happened with the color after `</script>`, alse, how can I modify the whole color pattern. much appriciate.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using both ESLint and Prettier, then you should configure only Prettier for the formatting since he will disable ESLint rules that affect formatting. You can create `.prettier.json` file in the root of your project and add this config:

```json
{
  "singleQuote": true,
  "semi": false
}
```